# How to read data from file?

Tags: java, java-io, objectinputstream

I have problem to read data from file . When I write data to file I write One object of array List to file. But when I read it back , It still read not stop. I have one method to read data like below.

```
    public ArrayList<Product> objectReader(String fileName)throws Exception{
            ArrayList<Product>pro=null;
            BufferedInputStream bfInput;
                bfInput=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
                ObjectInputStream obj=new ObjectInputStream(bfInput);
                    pro=(ArrayList<Product>) obj.readObject();

 //            the probelm when i try to output it
                    System.out.println(pro);
                    obj.close();
                    return pro;

        }
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Any exception thrown?

Comment: Please provide a complete MCVE.  The problem (whatever it is) is not manifest in the code you have shown us.

Comment: #MR Vishal Kamat when i try to output it . it still read not stop.

Comment: Your English is hard to understand.  What are you trying to output, and where?   The code you have shown us has no output statements.  That's why I think it would be better if you wrote an MCVE for us.  Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: code is not content error. But its output is not properly. when i want read element of arraylist , it print forever.

Comment: @narason you need to close every resource

Comment: and if possible use `try with catch` for simplicity

Comment: and one more thing, how you want to read data

Comment: are you readng `product object` because if you are doing then you need to `searilize them first`

Comment: i add them already

Comment: @holidayCoder - If I understand her correctly, the problem is that the `println` just goes on endlessly. I can't really dig her code...

Comment: Share your file...........

Comment: Ok thank you. i see my error. But i have one question "How can we performance to read data from file  . for example if have One Million record in file . First in my test performance it so slow.